# Exception "Invalid column name"

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I'm getting the following error while running locRecords.jsp

> An exception occurred processing JSP page /locRecords.jsp at line 268

```
<td><%=rs.getString("LOC_ID")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("LOC_NAME")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("LOC_CONTACT")%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString("LOC_ADDRESS")%></td>
<%if (rs.getString("BELONGED_TO") != null){%>
      <td><%=rs.getString("BELONGED_TO")%></td>
```

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
>       org.apache.jsp.locRecords_jsp._jspService(locRecords_jsp.java:432)
>       org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

Comment: It's a SQLException. It says "Invalid column name". So any of the strings passed to rs.getString() is not a valid column name in your database.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use  a column name that is not the same as the  relation(table) you used in your database.Please check your column names and your parameters for rs.getString().